Does lower_bound() return the same result with reverse iterators of a vector in increasing order vs forward iterators of a vector in decreasing order?
If I have 2 vectors, one in increasing order, and other decreasing:
vector<int> inc{1,2,3,4,6,7}, dec{7,6,4,3,2,1};

Do the following 2 expressions always give the same result? Or, is there any difference in how they work?
lower_bound(inc.rbegin(), inc.rend(), some_number, greater<int>()) // #1

lower_bound(dec.begin(), dec.end(), some_number, greater<int>()) // #2


Have you consulted cppreference yet? std::lower_bound, and std::upper_bound.  If so what is still unclear to you? And what is the output of your code? Have you tried on your own computer?

@PepijnKramer Yeah I did...but as I said, according to me they should semantically be equivalent but during a recent content on Codeforces, one got accepted while the other didn't. Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks!

Define "equivalent". If nothing else, they produce results of different types.

@IgorTandetnik Yeah so I get that one produces a reverse iterator...but besides that if I am just using the element pointed to by that returned pointer, do we get the same result always?

I would not expect a difference to be honest, and I cannot reproduce: https://onlinegdb.com/IT3xVq-5E (maybe you should show more of your code, could be the problem is somewhere else)

I'm reasonably sure that (r1==inc.rend() && r2=dec.end) || *r1 == *r2 should always be well-defined and true, if that's what you are asking.

Theoretically they should produce the same value, and for things like integers it shouldn't matter. But consider how you are producing the sequences. Given the same unordered sequence, you may perform a sort to produce the increasingly-ordered sequence, and another sort to produce the decreasingly-ordered sequence. If your sorting algorithm is not stable (meaning that any relatively ordered elements of the original sequence remain relatively ordered), then it's possible that two equivalent elements are not appropriately reversed in the reversed sequence.

From the algorithm's, std::lower_bounds's, perspective, there is no differance other than the iterator type (one is a reverse iterator and the other one is not), but it doesn't care about that.
It will perform the same algorithmic steps in both cases and return an iterator pointing at an element that carries the same value in both cases - or the end()/rend() iterator.
One minor difference could be in speed. I'd expect the version using reverse iterators to be a tad slower, but I haven't measured.
So, other than the difference in the returned iterator type and possibly one being slower than the other, you will get the same value out of both versions.

For fun, here's a quick-bench measurement of the two versions. You can play around with the ranges to see if and how that effects the outcome. The lower the bar, the faster it is. Blue is for the reverse iterator and yellow is for the normal iterator.


You're alluding to the fact a reverse iterator would involve some additional machinery in code (so incrementing the reverse iterator maps to effect stepping backward through elements of the vector).  With an optimised build, I wouldn't anticipate any significant difference of performance and it is "not impossible" that performance would have no measurable difference.

@Peter Yes, to all of it. One doesn't know until one measures. I added a benchmark to the answer. In clang, the reverse iterator version is much slower. In gcc, not as much, but still noticeably.
